# tag calendar in primefaces not display in navigator

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i am beginner in jsf and when i use tag calendar it's not display in Navigator and any error appear ; i use eclipce , jsf 2 , primefaces 4

here my code view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
    <h:form>

    <p:calendar value="#{ticket.dateCreation}" mode="inline"  />

    </h:form>
    </h:body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JSF 2.2 you should use the new namespaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

You should also include

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
```

just below the namespaces so Primefaces can include Javascript/CSS resources.

I hope you're not referring to Netscape Navigator :-)

Comment: Does any primefaces tag work? Did you see the h:head edit also?

Comment: the preblem is the version primefaces ,
I changed the version primefarces 4 to primefraces 5 and it's going very well work